# Create a Deribit signature string & hash

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, authorization

I have been trying to connect to my account with the Deribit testnet API and I can't figure out why my code is not working.

My Apps Script test function:

```
function callderibit() {
  var key = '2YZn85siaUf5A'                                            
  var secret = 'BTMSIAJ8IYQTAV4MLN88UAHLIUNYZ3HN' 
  var nonce = '1452237485895' ;

  var baseUrl = 'https://test.deribit.com';
  var action = '/api/v1/private/account'

  var string = 
  '_=' + nonce                                               
       + '&_ackey=' + key
       + '&_acsec=' + secret
       + '&_action='+ action;

  var hash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, 
  string);

  var hash_encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(hash);     

  var signature = key + '.' + nonce + '.' + hash_encoded ;

  var options = {'headers': {'X-Deribit-Sig': signature}}


  // Call the API
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + action , options  )

  //Parse the JSON reply
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  Logger.log(data);
  }
```

This is the signature I am producing:
2YZn85siaUf5A.1452237485895.KOlc7ELGnz8cjYp614ONxZlngo/z2AHMEjVdlHlW9Oo=

The signature I sould be getting is this one:
2YZn85siaUf5A.1452237485895.LQctRklxPiJDHJj9ZYp78Epilx7N78crGghzr1pvNlI=

---

### NEW INFO

As we found out, the provided js and py examples on deribits site are not functioning properly since they are producing a different hash than they should.

After this I got in contact with deribit and I got this reply:
.............................................................................

"Hi

I've attached Python examples for  API v1. You may also find Python, Nodejs wrappers for API v1 on our github page https://github.com/deribit

Please note, further development of API v1  has been ended -- though the API v1 is still available, we are more focused on API v2 https://docs.deribit.com/v2 "
.............................................................................

Attached py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import base64
import hashlib
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

api_key = 'API_KEY'
api_secret = 'API_SECRET'
instrument = 'BTC-PERPETUAL'
tstamp = '1485629332052'
price = 100
size = 1
params = (tstamp, api_key, api_secret, instrument, price, size)

data='_=%s&_ackey=%s&_acsec=%s&_action=/api/v1/private/buy&instrument=%s  
      &post_only=true&price=%0.2f&quantity=%d' % params

hashed = base64.b64encode(hashlib.sha256(data.encode()).digest())
signature = '%s.%s.%s' % (api_key, tstamp, hashed.decode())

headers = {"x-deribit-sig": signature, "content-type":"application/x-www-        
form-urlencoded"}

# important: in signature post_only=true, but in params it was True - so     
signature can't match
params={'instrument': instrument, 'post_only': 'true', 'price': 
'%0.2f'%price,'quantity': size}

url = 'https://test.deribit.com/api/v1/private/buy'
data = urlencode(params).encode()
request = Request(url, urlencode(params).encode(), headers)
json = urlopen(request).read().decode()
print(json)
```

Comment: Should `'_=' + 'nonce'` be `'_=' + nonce`?

Comment: you are right, I changed it! but the authorization is still not successful

Comment: When you use the example values provided in the [API docs](https://docs.deribit.com/rpc-authentication.html), does your code here produce the stated signature `2YZn85siaUf5A.1452237485895.LQctRklxPiJDHJj9ZYp78Epilx7N78crGghzr1pvNlI=` ? If not, then you are not constructing and hashing properly.

Comment: The hash dose look different, I just tried out the apiconsole and produced a bunch of signatures. I am producing a hash of a lenght of 64 instead of 58 (excluding key and nonce). Also the correct hash always has an '=' at the end.

Comment: I have amended the code as I saw that the hash needed to be encoded (base64). The signature I am now producing matches the ones I can get from the console, however I still dont have assess.

Comment: At [the sample script of the official document](https://docs.deribit.com/rpc-authentication.html), the digest algorithm is used. So how about ``var signature_hash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, string)``? I couldn't test about this. So if this was not the solution, I apologize.

Comment: thx for the suggestion I tried it out but it did not work, this is what I did:
var hash = Utilities.computeDigest(Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, string);           var hash_encoded = Utilities.base64Encode(hash);

I am trying to mimic the js from their site as much as possible: 
let signatureStringEncoded = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(signatureString);
    let binaryHash = crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", signatureStringEncoded);
    return
Here I see that they first encode and then hash. I tried that as well but is got a bunch of number instead

Comment: When ``_=1452237485895&_ackey=2YZn85siaUf5A&_acsec=BTMSIAJ8IYQTAV4MLN88UAHLIUNYZ3HN&_action=/api/v1/private/buy&instrument=BTC-15JAN16&price=500&quantity=1`` is used for the official sample scripts, Javascript and Python returns ``W29iamVjdCBQcm9taXNlXQ==`` and ``KOlc7ELGnz8cjYp614ONxZlngo/z2AHMEjVdlHlW9Oo=``, respectively. At Google Apps Script, the same value with Python is returned. But these are not the same with the sample result of ``LQctRklxPiJDHJj9ZYp78Epilx7N78crGghzr1pvNlI=``. From this, I worry about the issue of the official sample scripts. How do you think about this situation?

Comment: thx for pointing this out, I should have thought of this earlier. I have contacted deribit, lets see what the have to say if they reply.

Comment: @Saoma Thank you for replying. When you got the reply including the correct sample scripts, could you please tell me it? I would like to try to think of the method for achieving it using Google Apps Script.

Comment: Hey good morning, I got a reply with a revised py file and an example for a web socket. Apparently they have discontinued working on api v1 as they are now moving forward with v2. The email and files are in the original post.

Comment: @Saoma Thank you for replying and updating it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to succesfully connect to v2 Deribit API and retrieve account data using the following google apps script. Just in case it helps.

```
function deribitAccountSummary() {
  var clientId = 'xxx';
  var clientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
  var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() ).toString();
  var nonce = generateNonce(8);
  var uri = '/api/v2/private/get_account_summary?currency=BTC';
  var httpMethod = 'GET';
  var body = '';

  var requestData = httpMethod.toUpperCase() + '\n' + uri + '\n' + body + '\n';
  var stringToSign = timestamp + '\n' + nonce + '\n' + requestData;
  var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(stringToSign, clientSecret)
    .map(function(byte) {
      return ('0' + (byte & 0xFF).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    })
    .join('');

  var url = 'https://www.deribit.com' + uri;
  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'deri-hmac-sha256 id=' + clientId + ',ts=' + timestamp 
     + ',nonce=' + nonce + ',sig=' + signature,
  };

  var options = {
    'method': httpMethod,
    'headers': headers,
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(json);
}

function generateNonce(length) {
  var charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  var nonce = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    nonce += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));
  }
  return nonce;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).